# Linux Net Core error Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005

Tags: linux, .net-core

tengo un entorno Linux Centos 7, el cual NO tiene acceso a Internet, ya que esta en una red privada/cerrada.
Necesito instalar el entorno de desarrollo .net Core 3.1.x, para lo cual descargue desde la pagina https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1 la versión la correspondiente x64.

En la instalación, según la documentación, se debe descomprimir en un directorio/dotnet el contenido del archivo descargado. Luego, establecer en el .bash_profile, establecer algunos parámetros para que el ambiente este disponible.

Al ejecutar el comando dotnet new sln, me aparece el error : **Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá en la imagen,. se ve que tanto el sdk como el runtime, están accesibles.

Alguna idea de porque pasa esto?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

se trataba de un tema de permisos. al instalar como root, los demas usuarios no podian acceder a las carpoetas del runtime

Comment: que comando usaste para poder arreglarlo?